Group of order $2^kq$ has a normal Sylow $2$-subgroup
Let $G$ be a group of order $2^kq$ for some prime $q>2^k$ , denote $P$ and $Q$ one of the Sylow $2$-subgroup and Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$ respectively.
I have seen a comment that for such a group $G$ , the Sylow $2$-subgroup $P$ is normal. $\color{red}{\text{(update: this proposition is false)}}$
I can just prove that if $P$ is normal then $Q$ is normal too, as follows (my proof works for the group $G$ of order $p^kq$ for some prime $q>p^k$ , and $p=2$ is just a special case).

 Since $p$ and $q$ are primes, $\mathbf{gcd}(|P|,|Q|)=\mathbf{gcd}\big(p^k,q\big)=1$ . By Lagrange's Theorem (Theorem3.2.8 on page89 in Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra) applying to both $P$ and $Q$ , $|P\cap Q|$ divides both $|P|$ and $|Q|$ , namely $P\cap Q=1$ . Then by Proposition3.2.13 on page93 , $|PQ|=\frac{|P||Q|}{|P\cap Q|}=p^kq=|G|$ , thus $PQ=G$ . Because $P\unlhd G$ , by Theorem5.5.10 on page176 , $G\cong P\rtimes_{\varphi} Q$ for some homomorphism $\varphi$ from $Q$ to $\mathbf{Aut}(P)$ . To show that $G\cong P\times Q$ , by Proposition5.5.11 on page177 , it is equivalent to prove that $\mathsf{Hom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}\big(\mathbf{Aut}(P),Q\big)=\{0\}$ (and then $Q$ is also normal in $G$) and we shall prove it by order consideration. Note that $\mathbf{Aut}(P)\leqslant\mathbf{S}_P\cong\mathbf{S}_{p^k}$ where $\mathbf{S}_P$ is the symmetry group on $P$ and $\mathbf{S}_P$ is the symmetry group of degree $p^k$ , then by Lagrange's Theorem, $\#\mathbf{Aut}(P)\ \Big|\ \big|\mathbf{S}_{p^k}\big|=\big(p^k\big)!$ . Recall that $|Q|=q$ is a prime greater than $p^k$ , so $\mathrm{gcd}\big(\big|\mathbf{S}_{p^k}\big|,\big|Q\big|\big)=\mathbf{gcd}\big((p^k)!\ ,\,q\,\big)=1$ , implying $\mathbf{gcd}(\#\mathbf{Aut}(P),|Q|)=1$ . Then by the First Isomorphism Theorem for Groups (Theorem3.3.16 on page97) , we have $\mathbf{domain}\,\varphi/\mathbf{ker}\,\varphi\cong\mathbf{im}\,\varphi$ , hence $\#\varphi\big(\mathbf{Aut}(P)\big)$ divides $\#\mathbf{Aut}(P)$ , which together with the previous argument provides $\mathbf{gcd}(\#\varphi\big(\mathbf{Aut}(P)\big),|Q|)=1$ , that is, $\varphi\big(\mathbf{Aut}(P)\big)=1_Q$ and $\varphi$ must be the trivial homomorphism. Thereby we complete the proof.

Is there a general proof that for a group $G$ of order $2^kq$ for some prime $q>2^k$ , the Sylow 2-subgroup $P$ is normal? $\color{red}{\text{(update: this proposition is false)}}$

Where is the quote from?

It is a comment in the Chinese "Quora" (called ZhiHu) given by a graduated student learning group theory. But I found just now that $D_{2q}$ has non_normal sylow 2-subgroups where $D_{2q}$ denotes the dihedral group of order $2q$ . So it seems a wrong proposition. And my question has some typos, I have corrected them.

Yes, $S_3\cong D_3 $ is a counterexample.
